# Why does contour plot not show point(s) where function has a discontinuity?

Tags: plotting, discontinuity

Consider the following code, which defines a function with a discontinuity, and then generates a contour plot when the function equals that discontinuity.

```
f[x_, y_] := 
 Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x] + Log[y] + 2, x == 1 && y == 2}}, 
  Sqrt[x] + Log[y]];
ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == f[1, 2]}, {x, .5, 1.5}, {y, 1.5, 
  2.5}, {ContourStyle -> {Black}}]
```

The output of this is a blank plot.
[image]

**My question is:**

- Why is this a blank plot? (1,2) should be on the contour since, by definition, we are plotting the contour through (1,2). is there any way to fix this?

  - is it just that because it is just a point it cannot be displayed? If so, is there not a point-size option I can use to fix it?

---

Aside: **Bonus question**, as shown in the graph below, the points (9,2) and (1,2*Exp[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROcdA.png)) are also not included on the contour.

**Why are these not included on the contour?** I assume it is because of the discontinuity, but they have the correct value of the contour...

```
f[x_, y_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x] + Log[y] + 2, x == 1 && y == 2}}, 
   Sqrt[x] + Log[y]];
ContourPlot[{f[x, y] == f[1, 2]}, {x, .5, 15}, {y, 1.5, 
  25}, {ContourStyle -> {Black}, PlotPoints -> 500}]
```

gives an output of
[image]
even though (9,1) and (1,2*Exp[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROcdA.png)) should be on the contour, as shown by

```
{f[1, 2], f[1, 2 E^2], f[9, 2]}
(* Out {3+Log[2],1+Log[2 \[ExponentialE]^2],3+Log[2]} *)
```

Comment: Yes, only one point in the first cases. In the another cases, add `Exclusions -> None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

f[x_, y_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x] + Log[y] + 2, x == 1 && y == 2}}, Sqrt[x] + Log[y]];
```

The equation `f[x, y] == f[1, 2]` defines a single point in the region of interest

```
FindInstance[{f[x, y] == f[1, 2], 1/2 <= x <= 3/2, 3/2 <= y <= 5/2}, {x, 
  y}, Reals, 5]

(* {{x -> 1, y -> 2}} *)
```

To see the [`ContourPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContourPlot.html) use

```
ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, 1/2, 3/2}, {y, 3/2, 5/2},
 ContourStyle -> Black,
 Exclusions -> None,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
f2[x_, y_] := 
  Piecewise[{{Sqrt[x] + Log[y] + 2, x == 1 && y == 2}}, Sqrt[x] + Log[y]];

pts = {x, y} /. 
   FindInstance[{f2[x, y] == f2[1, 2], 1/2 <= x <= 15, 3/2 <= y <= 25}, 
     {x, y}, 20];

Show[
 ContourPlot[{f2[x, y] == f2[1, 2]},
  {x, 1/2, 15}, {y, 3/2, 25},
  ContourStyle -> Black,
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  Exclusions -> None],
 Graphics[{Red, AbsolutePointSize[4],
   Point[pts]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know that Mathematica automatically excludes such points. Is it a good practice to always specify "Exclusions->None", or to always do so when working with functions with discontinuities?

Comment: Sometimes people want to see exclusions. Just be aware that the option is there and use it when it helps to do what you are trying to achieve.